# What's the cause of the error with this C++ template code?

Tags: c++

This code results in a compile-time error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

template <unsigned short n>
class Vector {
    public:
        std::vector<float> coords;

        Vector();
        Vector(std::vector<float> crds);


        float distanceFrom(Vector<n> v);

        template <unsigned short m>
        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Vector<m>& v);
};



    template <unsigned short n>
Vector<n>(vector<float> crds) {  // HERE IS ERRRO

}
```

Compile error:

```
C:\CodeBlocks\kool\praks3\vector.h|29|error: expected ')' before '<' token|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Maybe you should do less writing code and more reading until you master the basics?

Comment: The best way of "mastering the basics" is not only reading but also trying to use it in some simple examples. Once you get over these mistakes, you will remember the constructs much better and (almost) never make the same mistakes twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you should define the constructor outside the class:

```
template <unsigned short n>
Vector<n>::Vector(std::vector<float> crds) {
//also notice this ^^^^                 
}
```

Comment: aaah ofcourse.. the extra Vector there..i totally forgot, thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
template <unsigned short n>
Vector<n>::Vector(vector<float> crds) {
}
```

EDIT: As others mentioned, if you're not `using namespace std;` you also need `std::vector<float>`

Comment: I would also include the `std::` prefix before `vector<float>`, just to be coherent with the class declaration. And it might not work this way (we don't know if he has an using directive somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

you probably miss std:: prefix in your `vector<float>`.

Comment: Yes, he would. Compiler can't recognize "vector" word.

Comment: @Erik:  Its one possibility the variety of errors in the code mean it could be any one of multiple issues, alas :(

Comment: That's likely also a problem, but the compilers **error message** is about the other problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vector::Vector(constructor args)
You just forgot to scope the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Should it be this?

```
template <> Vector<unsigned short>::Vector(Vector<float> crds) 
{
    // BLAH
}
```

It looks to me like you've got confused on template specialisation.