# How to overload a constructor outside of the class definition in c++

Tags: c++

Okay, so I have been working on a homework project and found a way that will let me finish the homework and get it turned in, but it is still bothering me.

I have a base class that is dynamically allocating some other classes, and a Derived class.

```
//header
class Base 
{
Private:
   Type *type_ptr;
Public:
   Base();
   Base(Type &new_type);
   //getters and setters
}

class Derived : public Base
{
Private:
  Type2 *type2_ptr;
Public:
 Derived();
 Derived(Type, Type2) : Base(Type);

}
```

What I want to figure out is what this should look like in my .cpp file, instead of doing it in-line like so,

```
Derived(Type new_type, Type2 new_type2): Base(new_type){
  type2_ptr = new Type2(new_type2);
};
```

edit: if I try something like the above in my .cpp that I get errors like this, always two of them too...

```
undefined reference to `vtable for Derived'
undefined reference to `vtable for Derived'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the cause of the error with this C++ template code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288696/whats-the-cause-of-the-error-with-this-c-template-code)

Comment: Seems like I'm looking at a quite different error, It compiles just fine but won't link.

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose such errors without code that can be compiled. Can you post a *minimal* but complete code-sample that reproduces the error?

Comment: I'll try to make it happen after my classes today. At this point I'm more curious what causes this kind of error.

Answer (score 3):

header:

```
/* Base same as yours */

class Derived : public Base
{
Private:
  Type2 *type2_ptr;
Public:
 Derived();
 Derived(Type&, Type2);
}
```

cpp:

```
Base::Base(): type_ptr(NULL)
{
// implementation goes here
}
Base::Base(Type &new_type): type_ptr(&new_type)
{
// implementation goes here
}


Derived::Derived()
{
// implementation goes here
}

Derived::Derived(Type& new_type, Type2 new_type2): Base(new_type), 
  type2_ptr(new Type2(new_type2))
{
// implementation goes here
}
```

note thet `new_type` is reference, not local variable in `Derived`, so variable passed to Derived must be in proper scope!

Answer (score 1):

Outside of class you need to use `Derived::` for all constructors and functions!

```
Derived::Derived(Type new_type, Type2 new_type2): Base(new_type)
{//^^^^^^^^^ note this  
  type2_ptr = new Type2(new_type2);
};
```

Also consider using `initialization-list` as much as possbible. Here is one example!

```
Derived::Derived(Type new_type, Type2 new_type2): Base(new_type), type2_ptr(new Type2(new_type2))
                                                                //^^^^ note this!
{

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not shown everything.  In the code you've shown, there
should be no vtable, since there are no virtual functions (and
the class isn't polymorphic, regardless of the inheritance.

Supposing that there are virtual functions, you should almost
certainly add a virtual destructor to Base.

Beyond that, the definition in the .cpp file should be:

```
Derived::Derived(Type new_type, Type2 new_type2)
    : Base(new_type)
    , type2_ptr(new Type2(new_type2))
{
}
```

Add the Derived:: in front of your definition, and there's
nothing in the code you expose which should cause problems.  You
really should provide a complete example of the code which does
cause the problem; otherwise, we can just guess.